# Sequelize hasMany fails

Tags: sql, orm, sequelize.js

I am trying to make a one-to-many association with Sequelize:

Here are my projects:

```
'use strict';
import { models } from '../sequelize/index';
var ProjectImages = require('./projectImages');

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const Projects = sequelize.define(
        'Projects',
        {
            id: {
                allowNull: false,
                autoIncrement: true,
                primaryKey: true,
                type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            },

            title: {
                type: DataTypes.STRING,
            },
        },
        {}
    );
    Projects.associate = function(models) {
        // associations can be defined here
        Projects.belongsToMany(models.Tags, { through: models.TagsProjects });
        Projects.hasMany(models.ProjectImages);
    };

    return Projects;
};
```

And here the images of the projects:

```
'use strict';
import { models } from '../sequelize/index';

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const ProjectImages = sequelize.define(
        'ProjectImages',
        {
            id: {
                allowNull: false,
                autoIncrement: true,
                primaryKey: true,
                type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            },

            img: {
                type: DataTypes.STRING,
            },

            createdAt: {
                allowNull: false,
                type: DataTypes.DATE,
                defaultValue: DataTypes.literal('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'),
            },

            updatedAt: {
                allowNull: false,
                type: DataTypes.DATE,
                defaultValue: DataTypes.literal('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'),
            },
        },
        {}
    );

    return ProjectImages;
};
```

I am syncing the database with something similar to [this snippet](https://gist.github.com/ihavenoidea14/0dab8b461c057c427829fdc99bfb6743). If I don't try to create any row in ProjectImages I don't get any error; but if I try to create row with this (the project with id: 1 exist):

```
"ProjectImages": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "img": "https://fakeimg.pl/500x500/",
        "ProjectsId": 1
    }
],
```

I get this error:

```
Executing (default): INSERT INTO `ProjectImages` 
(`id`,`img`,`createdAt`,`updatedAt`,`ProjectId`) 
VALUES
(1,'https://fakeimg.pl/500x500/',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,1);
[1] Unhandled rejection SequelizeForeignKeyConstraintError: 
Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails 
(`9uhfggfhf2`.`projectimages`, 
CONSTRAINT `projectimages_ibfk_1` 
FOREIGN KEY (`ProjectId`) 
REFERENCES `Projects` (`id`) 
ON DELETE SET NULL 
ON UPDATE CASCADE)
```

Also, if I don't add a row to ProjectsImages when syncing I don't get any error as well, and if I try to insert the row manually in DB with:

```
INSERT INTO `ProjectImages` (`id`,`img`,`createdAt`,`updatedAt`,`ProjectsIdA`) 
VALUES (1,'https://fakeimg.pl/500x500/',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,1);
```

It works without any problem.

Does anyone know what is going on there?

Answer (score 0):

As I said, I was using something similar to [this](https://gist.github.com/ihavenoidea14/0dab8b461c057c427829fdc99bfb6743) in order to sync with the DB.

At the end of the snippet I had to seed the data:

```
seed([
    articles, 
    projectImages, 
    projects, 
    tags, 
    tagsProjects, 
    users, 
    usersLogins
]);
```

And as you will notice, I was inserting `projectImages` before creating `projects`. Placing things in the proper order solved the problem.

```
seed([
    articles, 
    projects, 
    projectImages, 
    tags, 
    tagsProjects, 
    users, 
    usersLogins
]);
```

:)